# examples of non-unital commutative $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I know that all the non-unital commutative $C^*$ algebras are isomorphic to $C_0(\Omega)$,where $\Omega$ is a locally compact space.
Can anyone show me some common non-unital commutative examples.I only know the $c_0$ space.

Comment: You already answered the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The algebra $c_0$ is $C_0(\mathbb N)$. All you need is other examples of non-compact, locally compact spaces. The next familiar one is $\mathbb R$. Or $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.